# How to share a mysql database with another computer in the same network

Tags: mysql

I whish to share a mysql database in my computer with 3 more computers in the same network. These computers use msaccess to manage databases. I'm using the ODBC connector to connect mysql database with msaccess in all computers. This network has dynamic IPs and all computers run Windows 7, except one with XP. My question is: what host adress should I put in the remote computer in the ODBC settings since the IPs are dynamic?

Thank you.

Comment: Use your computer's WINS/NetBIOS name?

Comment: You might want to go through this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connecting.html

Comment: Thank you. I think windows 7 don't have netBios name (sorry for my ignorance).