# Make a ruby on rails API to share a mysql database with a php system already done

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, api, pdo

I want to create a shared database, for a few days I searched for a solution but the most certainly post not bring me the solution ([How to share a mysql database with another computer in the same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043198/how-to-share-a-mysql-database-with-another-computer-in-the-same-network))

How can I create a ruby on rails API to share a database 'in the same server' within a php application (already created) which is already consuming a method that brings me the content of another ONLINE API to rails sucker?

How can I share a database between rupiApi and myphpsytem?

Comment: i have cpanel administration almost full

Comment: I think you just have to use mysql2 gem in ruby  https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions/0.5.2 and then follow the documentation(https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.5.2) there for your setup.

Comment: great, i go to install this gem in my gemfile, is there any other configuration to goal this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description, you have a PHP application using the mysql db. Now you want a rails application to use the same db for API's .

Steps:

1) Add gem in gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.10'
```

Above code will load the mysql gem and its dependencies in the application so that you can use the same and connect with the database.

2) In config/database.yml use the credentials to connect with the database

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci
pool: 5
host: YOUR_HOST_IP
username: YOUR_USERNAME
password: YOUR_PASSWORD

development:
  <<: *default
  database: YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME

test:
  <<: *default
  database: YOUR_TEST_DB_NAME

production:
  <<: *default
  pool: 10
  database: YOUR_PRODUCTION_DB_NAME
```

Note: I have specified default settings for all environment, but you can specifify settings if they are different for different environments.